# Posting Input value as param to web service API in Angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ngresource

I have started learning Angular and I'm stuck on something that should be trivial. I'm from a Rails background and created a very simple Rails web-service that manages a MailingList. Currently 2x API endpoints exist in my web-service:

```
/api/v1/mailing_lists [GET]
/api/v1/mailing_lists [POST]
```

The POST endpoint requires a valid email as a PARAM in the API call. And this is where I'm stuck. How do I pass this param to my API in Angular? I've tried using solutions from around the web but I'm just not getting it right. Here's what I have thus far:

In my services.js:

```
angular.module('webFrontendApp.services', []).factory('MailingList', function($resource) {
    var data = $resource(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/mailing_lists.json',
      {},
      {
        // 'get': { method:'GET', cache: false},
        'query': { method:'GET', cache: false, isArray:true },
        'save': {method: 'POST', cache: false }
      });
    return data;
});
```

In app.js

```
....
.when('/list/new', {
        templateUrl: 'views/list-new.html',
            controller: 'MailingListCtrl'
      })

....
```

Controller as mailinglist.js

angular.module('webFrontendApp.controllers', [])

```
.controller('MailingListCtrl', function($scope, MailingList) {
    // Get all posts
    $scope.mailing_lists = MailingList.query();

    // Our form data for creating a new post with ng-model
    $scope.memberData = {};
    $scope.newMember = function() {
      var member = new MailingList($scope.memberData);
      member.$save();
    };
});
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="newMember()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="memberData.email" placeholder="New mailing list member" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I submit the form, nothing seems to happen, but I am receiving a 405 error response from my web service. After looking into my Web Service logs, I can see that a POST request was received but no params were passed and thus it was rejected.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

PS. I have made sure to Enable CORS on my Rails app.

Answer (score 1):

Pass params inside `$save` method, pass post_data inside `MailingList`, so basically this should work

```
$scope.newMember = function() {
    var member = new MailingList();
    member.$save({email: $scope.memberData.email});
};
```